# Cant make text editor with draft,js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I have a basic component of text editor with draft js

The problem is that I can't choose a font, font size, color, add a photo, choose an emoji, or create a link.
What do I need to do to make this work? What to add?
[dont work these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8whg.png)

I have a basic component of text editor with draft js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import { EditorState, convertToRaw } from "draft-js";
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
import draftToHtml from "draftjs-to-html";

export const TextEditor = () => {
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());

const onEditorStateChange = (newEditorState) => {
    setEditorState(newEditorState);
};

return (
    <div>
        <Editor
            editorState={editorState}
            toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
            wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
            editorClassName="editorClassName"
            onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
        />
        <textarea
            disabled
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            value={draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))}
        ></textarea>
    </div>
    );
};
```